# To play Youtube Video in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to play youtube videos in my iOS App. I searched for that but the only solution I found is to embed youtube videos in the iOS app, in which video plays in webview, so in that, we can scroll and also play other videos which are in suggestion.
I don't want to play video in webview, I want to play video just like it plays in player and user cannot scroll it.
Is there any solution for that in Swift and also I don't want to use libraries which are against terms and condition of Youtube

Comment: You can follow [this the blog post](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2017/03/play-youtube-video-in-ios-app.html) regarding playing youtube video] and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44432149/988169)

Comment: @Prathamesh :- Refer this documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: @Coder it is in Objective-C, I want implementation in swift.

Comment: @Prathamesh UIKit is also written in ObjC, you may want to look for an alternative

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's another solution if you don't want to use the API provided by YouTube and instead continue using a `UIWebView`.

YouTube has functionality to load any video in fullscreen in a webview without any of the scrolling features using a URL in the format `https://www.youtube.com/embed/<videoId>`.

For example, to load Gangnam Style using this method, simply direct the UIWebView to the URL https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0.

Comment: I tried your second answer, but that import statement is giving me the error "no such module found" I did every step of cocoapods.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that their documentation is out of date.  The pod name that worked for me was `youtube-ios-player-helper` instead of `YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper`.  I just updated my other answer with the steps that worked for me, if you're still interested.

Answer (score 20):

The API that YouTube provides to embed videos in iOS apps is indeed written in Objective-C, but it works just as well in Swift.

To install the library via CocoaPods, [follow the CocoaPods setup instructions](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) and add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod ‘youtube-ios-player-helper’, ‘~> 0.1’
```

Once you have run `pod install`, be sure to use the `.xcworkspace` file from now on in Xcode.

To import the pod, simply use the following import statement at the top of your Swift files:

```
import youtube_ios_player_helper
```

You can then create youtube player views as follows:

```
let playerView = YTPlayerView()
```

You can include this view in your layouts as you would any other UIView.  In addition, it includes all of the functions listed in the YouTube documentation.  For instance, to load and play a video, use the following function:

```
playerView.load(withVideoId: videoId);
```

Where `videoId` is the string id found in the URL of the video, such as `"9bZkp7q19f0"`.

Comment: video is not available , i got this error while using this library.

Comment: the problem is that you can't play video with normal quality (always medium, which is 360p)

Comment: and this official helper is just UIWebView + YouTube iframe API, so you can find many other non official libraries (even Swift + WKWebView)

Answer (score 3):

#### Play youtube video in Swift 4.0

```
if let range = strUrl.range(of: "=") {
        let strIdentifier = strUrl.substring(from: range.upperBound)        
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(strIdentifier) { 

            [weak playerViewController] (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
            if let streamURLs = video?.streamURLs, let streamURL = 
                (streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ?? 
                streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.hd720] ?? 
                streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.medium360] ?? 
                streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.small240]) {
                    playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
                } else {
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There also are solutions for playing Youtube Videos in an app on Github.

Like this one: https://github.com/rinov/YoutubeKit

Or this one: https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

Just simply add the pod for the project that you want to use, install the pod in terminal, and you can use the functionality in that project.

Hope that this is helpful.

Comment: Adding example code inline would improve your answer

Answer (score 0):

I've created an extension to make Youtube video playable in `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`. By using [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508538/11077258)'s solution.

```
extension String { 
/*
 Below variable will convert youtube ID to embedded Youtube link. 
*/
    var youtubeVideoURL: String?{
        let url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(self)"
        return url
    }


/*    
Here below variable return us Youtube ID from URL String.

e.g. if Youtube link = "https://youtu.be/-zD8M66aAA4" then we'll get YoutubeID = "-zD8M66aAA4"
*/
    var youtubeID: String? { 
        let pattern = "((?<=(v|V)/)|(?<=be/)|(?<=(\\?|\\&)v=)|(?<=embed/)|(?<=shorts/))([\\w-]++)"
        
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: count)

        guard let result = regex?.firstMatch(in: self, range: range) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return (self as NSString).substring(with: result.range)
    }
}
```

- Use

```
let ytLink = "https://youtu.be/-zD8M66aAA4"

let videoUrl = ytLink.youtubeID?.youtubeVideoURL
print(videoUrl)

/*
Result:- https://www.youtube.com/embed/-zD8M66aAA4
*/
```

> We can directly play above url in WebView

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: videoUrl)
webView?.load(urlRequest)
```