# Can't reproduce videos from vimeo or youtube in my swift 4 app

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I want to reproduce some video. I have seen people download the video, is this necessary? Can I just do

```
 guard let videoURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCVcqjjvZBM") else { return }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player

        self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
            playerController.player?.play()
        }
```

If I do this, the video never loads and I see the a play button with a line over it.

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499332/to-play-youtube-video-in-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL won't work has you are linking to the [Youtube page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCVcqjjvZBM), not the video itself. If you entered the URL below as your string it should work because the request is a `.mp4`.

https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4

You need to work out if you can find the actual video URL of the Youtube video you would like to play.

Looking further into it, the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) does what you require.